# How to use promql group by without using aggregate functions in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I am trying to create a query that groups the data by "Api" field and selects a value field by using prometheus and grafana.

My sample query (promql) is `max (application_apidbacesscount_total) by (Api) [30m:1m]`. This works for getting max value with grouping the data by "Api" field.

How can i do that using grafana's panel? Is it possible to give Grafana a base query and modify it with panel fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a new widget and add the query:

```
max(rate(application_apidbacesscount_total[$__range])) by (Api)
```

[image]

Using `[$__range]` instead of a fixed range will apply the values of rage selector from Grafana

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don’t have “application_apidbaccess_total”. I am using CounterOptions as metric registry. What should I do to get the application_apidbaccess_total? In addition, my main purpose is get rid of the “max” function. I want to call aggregate functions from grafana. Is that possible?

Comment: In order to properly answer, can you share some real metrics?